# Get validation message from JQuery validator

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

Using MVC, .Net Core 2.1, bootstrap, JQuery Unobtrusive Validation...
Is there anyway to extract the 'validation' error message from within a javascript function?

With this as my model, note the error message : "String 1 is required"

```
public class TestObj
{
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "String 1 is required.")]
    public string str1 { get; set; }
    public TestObj() { }
    public TestObj(string i_str)
    {
        this.str1 = i_str;
    }
}
```

This is my controller

```
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        TestObj model = new TestObj();
        model = new TestObj("test1");
        return View(model);
    }
```

This as the cshtml

```
<form asp-action="Test" asp-controller="Home" method="post" id="myform">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2" style="width:5em;">
            <input asp-for="@Model.str1" class="form-control small_inp_box" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both; margin-top:1em;"></div>
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div style="clear:both; margin-top:1em;">
        <label id="lbl_msg1"></label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" />
</form>
```

And this as the JavaScript

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#lbl_msg1").text("Ready");
        $(".small_inp_box:first").focus();
    });
    $(".small_inp_box").focusout(function () {
        if (!$(this).valid()) {
            $(this).addClass("red");
            console.log("invalid!");
            console.log($(this).dataset.valRequired);
        }
        else {
            $(this).removeClass("red");
            console.log("valid!");
        }
    })
</script
```

Can I get the Required Validation Message "String 1 is required" from within the focusout function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it is the best way, but it should work. Put this into the focusout function:

```
var fv = $('#myform').validate();

// setTimeout is needed to let validation to complete
var currentElement = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    let error = fv.errorList.filter(function (e) { return e.element == currentElement; })[0];
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

Comment: AlbertK, I accepted your answer and up voted your response. The filter did not work quite right, I am still reviewing that, but the fv.errorList was what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Here is a [workable example](https://jsfiddle.net/20z9tyLx/). It looks like the filter works.

Comment: I dropped your original answer into my page and it now it works perfectly. Not sure what I did wrong the first time, anyway's thanks for the follow up, I'll be more careful in the future...